# Extract generic type not returning input type

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Given this sample code:

```
type keys = {
    a: number
    b: string
}

class Model<T extends number, U extends string> { }

class ExtendedModel<T extends keys & {
    c: boolean
}> extends Model<T['a'], T['b']> {
   // private Keys: T // <---- try to uncomment this line
}

type ExtractExtendedModelT<ExtendedExtendedModel> = ExtendedExtendedModel extends ExtendedModel<infer U> ? U : never

class Test extends ExtendedModel<{
    a: 1
    b: '2'
    c: false
}> { }

type TestGenericType = ExtractExtendedModelT<Test>  // <---- and see the type difference
```

Why can't i get the inputted generic type of class Test which is supposed to be `{ a: 1, b: '2', c: false }` **ONLY IF** i omit the private variable on ExtendedModel? While if i register the variable, i can correctly extract the type?

The problem is, i don't want to add any unused variable to my class.
Can someone please help me understand why is this happening and help me get around this?

[Link to TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20keys%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20number%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Model%3CT%20extends%20number%2C%20U%20extends%20string%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Aclass%20ExtendedModel%3CT%20extends%20keys%20%26%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20boolean%0A%7D%3E%20extends%20Model%3CT%5B'a'%5D%2C%20T%5B'b'%5D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20private%20Keys%3A%20T%20%2F%2F%20%3C----%20try%20to%20uncomment%20this%20line%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20ExtractExtendedModelT%3CExtendedExtendedModel%3E%20%3D%20ExtendedExtendedModel%20extends%20ExtendedModel%3Cinfer%20U%3E%20%3F%20U%20%3A%20never%0A%0Aclass%20Test%20extends%20ExtendedModel%3C%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20'2'%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20false%0A%7D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Atype%20TestGenericType%20%3D%20ExtractExtendedModelT%3CTest%3E%20%2F%2F%20%3C----%20and%20see%20the%20type%20difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to**

TypeScript can only infer the type `T` if there are members that uses `T`.

TypeScript has a [FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot---) about this:

> When inferring the type of T in the function call, we try to find members of type T on the x argument to figure out what T should be. Because there are no members which use T, there is nothing to infer from, so we return {}.